# Java web start launch app with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm working on a web site that has the need for full access on the clients computer . I found that Web Start is the solution (not applet) creating a java desktop application starting from the browser .

Problem is that the jnlp file needs to be downloaded every time the app starts for a task that's done very often.

I don't want the user to create a desktop shortcut or launche it from app manager . I whould like to start the app from the browser with javascript something like :

```
navigator.appManager.start("app");
```

If it can't be done maybe I can create a browser plugin , so I can have access to that app . So when the app first starts it install it self on the machine . 
It crossed my mind to make an applet to start the app.

Tried the example in the "duplicate" . It just opens a new window with the specific address.

```
BasicService bs = (BasicService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");
bs.showDocument(new URL("http://adress"));
```

Again I want to start the jnlp wep app without promting the user to download the jnlp with the exception of the first time.

Comment: In JS one may click a link `<a id="..." href="... .jnlp">`, n'est pas?

Comment: That will pop a download dialog . Open with/Save ...

Comment: Sorry not a duplicate. I was a little busy and had no time to try jnlp applet. The BasicService.showDocument will pop a download dialog with a next jnlp not what I need.